# Add Multiple User Control of the Same Type to a Page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Similar questions to this one have been asked but none seem to address my exact situation here's what I am trying to do.

I have a user control that manages student info. i.e. FirstName, LastName, Address etc.

I have a webpage/form that has a button on it. "Add Student". What I want to accomplish is for a new StudentInfo control to be added to the webform after each click.

My current code looks something like this

```
Private Sub btnAddStudent_Click(sender as object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Dim lStudentInfo as Control

LoadControl("~/StudentInfo.ascx")

Me.placeholder1.controls.add(lStudentInfo)

End Sub
```

With this code only one StudentInfo control is added and upon pressing the "Add" button again a new StudentInfo control isnt added below the first one and the text/data entered within the first  control is cleared.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that every time you do a postback your previous control was lost.  Remember, every postback uses a brand new instance of your page class.  The instance you added the control to last time was *destroyed* as soon as the http request finished — possibly before the browser even finished loading it's DOM.

If you want a control to exist for every postback you have to add it *on every postback*.

Additionally, if you want ViewState to work for the control you need to add it *before the Load event for the page*.  This means either on Init or PreInit.

```
Private Sub btnAddStudent_Click(sender as object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.placeholder1.controls.add(LoadControl("~/StudentInfo.ascx"))
    Session("NewStudentControls") += 1
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Init(sender as object, e as system.eventargs)
     For i As Integer = 1 To Session("NewStudentControls")
          Me.placeholder1.controls.add(LoadControl("~/StudentInfo.ascx"))
     Next
End Sub
```