# Dynamically creating/loading a user control only works once!

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dynamically-generated

```
protected void addMoreDay_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control OneMoreDay = LoadControl("~/controls/Days/DayAdd.ascx");
            Days_div.Controls.Add(OneMoreDay);
        }
```

I load my userControl dynamically to a div element .. but the problem is that it works only once! .. I mean I click the `addMoreDay_btn` button and it works then I try to click it again it won't create another instance of my control!

**Edit**

I think it works but it doesn't save the last created one .. it just replaces it with the newly created control .. and still I don't how to solve this! =S

Comment: Try adding two controls in that function instead of one. Does it have two if you do this? If no, then the problem is elsewhere (as in, the Div is getting wiped out somewhere)

Comment: actually it's more complicated than that .. It's about page Life Cycle .. I have to put all my controls in the array and specify the number of instances to created in the PreInit event .. I found this video (it's complicated and I'm not understanding it so far enough to build this) but it's all what I have for now >> http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is occurring because the dynamically added control is being destroyed on each postback right before it is created again. In order to have dynamic controls persist across postbacks, you'll have to add them every time the page posts back.

Try the following code.  Notice that the controls are being added in the Page_Init method:

```
protected void addMoreDay_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control OneMoreDay = LoadControl("~/controls/Days/DayAdd.ascx");
    Days_div.Controls.Add(OneMoreDay);
    Session["MyControl"] += 1
}


protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Session["MyControl"]; i++) {
        Control OneMoreDay = LoadControl("~/controls/Days/DayAdd.ascx");
        Days_div.Controls.Add(OneMoreDay);        
    }
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466760/add-multiple-user-control-of-the-same-type-to-a-page)

Comment: Yh I just figured out that they get destroyed somehow because of the page cycle and the postbacks .. but I don't get why the code for creating the control is repeated twice, and is there's a type of variable that will last through the postbacks instead of the Session variable cause it's an object and I'm facing some problems with it in c#, plus i don't it will be optimum to put a load on the session variable in a real world application .. what do you think ?

Comment: This is not working properly, because it creates an instance when I refresh the page too!

Comment: How important is it to have ViewState maintained for your controls?  If you don't need it, then you can move the code from the Page_Init method to the addMoreDay_btn_Click event.  However, if you need to maintain viewstate then you'll have to add another session variable to check if the page was refreshed or not.  Either way, it is definitely a solvable problem.

Comment: by ViewState you mean if the user refreshed the page or added one more day do I want to keep the data in the already created boxes, if so then yeah that would be great.  but how can I check if the page is refreshed!? can you help with a little more code or details